# Javascript detects animationend as if it was animationstart

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to trigger a function after an animation ends, but it triggers even before the animation starts. I don't know what can be wrong. I've checked my code multiple times and even made a simpler one, which is the one I'm showing here.

I have an element animated through CSS, and another hidden through CSS:

```
<div class= "container">
  <div id="animated" style="background-color: lime; animation: changeColour 5s;">CONTENT</div>
  <div id="hidden" style="visibility: hidden;">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Then, I have Javascript set an event listener to change the "hidden" visibility property to "visible"

```
var elementHidden = document.getElementById("hidden")
var elementAnimated = document.getElementById("animated")
elementAnimated.addEventListener("animationend", afterAnimation());

function afterAnimation() {
  elementHidden.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

And this is my animation:

```
@keyframes changeColour {
  0% {background-color: lime}
  50% {background-color: aqua}
  100% {background-color: lime}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **imediately** causing `afterAnimation` to run because you are calling it using: `afterAnimation()`.

Event listeners want **references** to functions.

In other words:

```
// Not this
elementAnimated.addEventListener("animationend", afterAnimation());

// This
elementAnimated.addEventListener("animationend", afterAnimation /* without () */);
```

The way you have it written right now, `afterAnimation` immediately changes visibility and then implicitly returns `undefined`.  You are basically writing:

```
afterAnimation();
elementAnimated.addEventListener("animationend", undefined);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, by the way.  Very clear / easy to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will never forget an event listener syntax again with this. Excellent answer indeed!